# speichern vs. abspeichern

Tags: meaning, difference, prefix

The meaning of the words "speichern" and "abspeichern" seem pretty close to each other in my view.

In my understanding, in the context of computerprograms/sofwares both of them means "to save" or "to store" (for example data on the harddrive).

Could someone enlight me the differences between the meanings of those two words.

Comment: As per the site’s rules: Please add what you found when consulting your dictionary or what you understood so far, thanks!

Comment: @Stephie: I checked Wiktionary, DWDS and dict.cc without much progress. English Wiktionary does not have *abspeichern*, and the definitions in German Wiktionary and DWDS seem to be the same except for phrasing. I think the question already includes the information you can get from a dictionary, that both mean to store information.

Answer (score 2):

While *speichern* indeed conveys everything contained in *save*, *abspeichern* in most cases puts an emphasis to the target location, so a typical use would be:

> ... habe die Datei im Dokumentenordner abgespeichert.

There is also, as in *einen Vorgang abschließen* a frequent component of finality in the *ab* prefix, as shown in:

- *etwas unter xxx ablegen*
- [abheften](https://www.dwds.de/wb/abheften) (properly filed as opposed to still lying around on the desk)
- *das hab ich abgespeichert* (I memorized that well and won't forget it)

Answer (score 2):

"Speichern" is a more general verb that refers to save or store something on a more permanent medium (for example, data from a computer's working memory to a hard disc). This can be an automated process, without human involvement. Examples would be an automatic backup copy, created every ten minutes by your word processor, or an automatic backup of your data every night to an external medium.

"Abspeichern" has a more intentional vibe to it. If you "abspeichern" your document, you intentionally and actively trigger the storage process. As guidot mentioned in his answer, there's also an idea of finality or completion to it. If you "abspeichern" while still working on something (which is a good idea in most cases), you can also use "zwischenspeichern" (this has a different meaning in some technical contexts, though).